# how to assert a binary multiline value in python using pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, stringio

I have the following scenario using `python3`:

```
type(file_pointer)
=> <class '_io.BytesIO'>
```

then

```
file_pointer.get_value()

# result below

b'simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'
```

what is the good way of asserting the above with `python` and `pytest` based on the fact its a multiline

I have tried:

```
assert file_pointer == (
  'b'simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the' 
  'industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a' 
  'galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only' 
  'five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially' 
  'unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets'
  'containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software' 
  'like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.''
)
```

and it does not seem to work

Any help would be helpful thanks in advance.

Comment: Asserting that the whole content is always the same ?

Comment: "based on the fact its a multiline" This doesn't seem to be the case. There are no newlines in ``file_pointer.get_value()``. Your reference string is missing spaces, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use triple quotes.  The original one-line assignment was breaking where the word `industry's` had an apostrophe in it.

```py
assert file_pointer.get_value() == (
  b"""simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.""")
```

Comment: Simple ``"``-quotes should be sufficient as well.

Comment: That's true, but that could break with other reference strings.  The preferred/pythonic approach for long-format bodies of text is triple-quoting, I believe.